# Add row in GridControl Devexpress onClick

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I'm using devexpress gridcontrol, and I want to generate 10 rows automatically on Click, I have researched some sources and says that it doesn't have a property like the standard GridView to add rows like gridView.Rows.Add();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to add rows in your grid :

. Your gridDataSource property should be set

. Make your view editable

```
 gridView1.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
 gridView1.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = NewItemRowPosition.Bottom;
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            gridView1.AddNewRow();
        }
```

. Set the position of the NewItemRowPosition of your view

```
gridView1.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = NewItemRowPosition.Bottom;
```

if you use the datatable as source you can write :

```
 DataTable tabe = new DataTable();
  gridControl1.DataSource = table;
  DataRow newLigne = table.NewRow();
  table.Rows.Add(newLigne);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that ,with pleasure

Comment: how am I going to add data to the new rows?

Comment: Are you using a DataTable as DataSource ?

Comment: Actually, my real scenario is that I have a ComboBoxEdit (containing January - December) inside my gridControl ... so once I generate the rows... the month names should be displayed in those cells, so my problem is it's not displaying since it's a combobexedit it's generating every new row.